# Runtime error 438 at with .printout

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have the following code, but it gives an Run-time error "438" at:

```
wdRng.PrintOut
```

If I change this to

```
MsgBox wdRng
```

it does give a MsgBox with the selection. So something is wrong with the PrintOut method. Anyone any suggestions what is wrong?

```
Dim i As Long, wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object, wdRng As Object

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  For i = 1 To 200
Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("\\path\Machine\Results" & i & ".doc", False, True, False)
With wdDoc
  Set wdRng = .Range(0, 0)
  With .Range
       With .Find
             .Text = "END"
             .Forward = True
             .MatchWholeWord = True
             .MatchCase = True
             .Execute
           End With
           If .Find.found = True Then
           wdRng.End = .Duplicate.Start
           wdRng.PrintOut
         End If
       End With
       .Close False
     End With
   Next
   .Quit
End With
Set wdRng = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like `.Printout` method for `Range object` in MS Word.

Try this logic instead of `wdRng.Printout`:

```
wdRng.Select
wdApp.PrintOut ,,WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintSelection
```

or 
    wdDoc.PrintOut , , WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintSelection

Edit- try any of these lines for `.PrintOut`:

```
wdDoc.PrintOut , , 1
wdApp.PrintOut ,, 1
```

Comment: The selection works, but at the .printout method gives an error. Run-time error "424". I just straight up copy pasted it, any idea where i go wrong?

Comment: very strange... try with `wdDoc.PrintOut , , WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintSelection` instead of `wdApp.Printout` line

Comment: Still the same error. I work with office 2013, can there be a difference??. Secondly, can it be something like      wdDoc.Printout Range:= wdRng

Comment: Also the document is opened as read only, can that cause any problems?

Comment: see my edit, especially for lines with number at the end

Comment: I had figured it out myself too. I used  wdDoc.Printout , Range:=1          thank you very much for your help